# Downvote without consequences?

Tags: support

Just curious:

I checked my behaviour on upvoting / downvoting; the rate is almost 30:1, which means I am not much of a downvoter. A few days ago however one of these rare occasions took place, and I was prepared to be "knocked out" by the loss of no less than 1 point reputation.

However, up to now, it has not had any effect; my reputation still ends with 8 or 3, would have been 7 or 2 now.

Is this an error in the system or is there another reason?

Comment: was it a question or answer?

Comment: @Mateo the downvote was on a question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no rep consequences on voting on questions.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that! Thanks.